# Are purely science based questions on topic?

Tags: discussion

I am more interested in the science behind cooking than how to make my food taste better.  Would a question that is *only* for the sake of food science be on topic?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, food science is totally fine, as long as it's the science of something you actually do in practice in cooking.

If you find yourself asking theoretical questions though, or getting to the level of things that have no direct effect on the food, that's probably pushing it. Some of those things might work on the dedicated science sites (chemistry, biology, physics).

Remember the rule in the help center:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face.

Your previous question about energy efficient cooking struck me as potentially a bit too theoretical, but I figured I'd let it slide since conserving fuel while camping is a legitimate concern, and maybe there's some similar situation with an electric stove. But if you're just setting up hypothetical cooking situations, that's not really the kind of thing we're looking for.

Similarly, your question about safe ingredients becoming dangerous when mixed is a good question not as a trivia question about unusual situations, but because it helps us tell people that everything normal is safe.